# select and retrieve data from cells in an HTML table using PHP

Tags: php

I have this table passed onto a php file using javascript through the code below:

```
    var tbl = document.getElementById("prtable").innerHTML;
    save(tbl);

    function save(tbl)
    {
        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
                    {


                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "save.php", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                xmlhttp.send("q=" +tbl);
            }
}
```

Then in the PHP file:

```
    $table = $_POST['q'];
    echo $table;   //test display
```

is there a way to do it like this in order to select a specific cell in table?

```
document.getElementById('tableID').rows.item(1).getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML
```

Does php have an equivalent for this javascript code?

What I want to do with it is to be able to retrieve the data in each of the  elements. I've searched for answers online but I've been stuck on this problem for hours now. If anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

By the way, the echo $table test displays something like this:

```
<tr>
    <th>PR Number</th>
    <th>Item Code</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Unit of Measure</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>PR001</td><td>IC001</td><td>Gloves (Plastic)</td><td>Pc</td><td>20.00</td><td>2</td><td>40.00</td></tr><tr><td>PR001</td><td>IC002</td><td>Gloves (Rubber)</td><td>Pc</td><td>25.00</td><td>3</td><td>75.00</td></tr></thead>
```

Comment: Is this table produced by your application? It seems daft to send a HTML table over a POST request to the server IMO. It would be better in a format like JSON or XML.

Comment: Simple HTML DOM might help. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net if you do want to keep doing it with the table.

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function str_get_html() in D:\jongkee\PHP\wamp\www\capstone\entry\save.php on line 148". I used $html = str_get_html('$table');

Comment: is there no way to do it like document.getElementById('tableID').rows.item(1).getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML in javascript? Does php have an equivalent for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, there isn't a native PHP function to do what you're looking to do.  You need to understand what your Javascript and PHP code is actually doing.

Your Javascript is rolling up your table into a serialized format and then passing it into PHP.  Your PHP then just reads your table data as one very long string.

What you want to do is use RegEx to parse out the various values inside of the string, and you're ultimately going to be better served in the long term learning RegEx rather than importing a new function.  I also agree with AeroX, since you control both sides of the application you'd probably be better off passing in JSON or XML and then you can very easily iterate through that.

Last but not least, you really want to sanitize your inputs.  This block of code:

```
$table = $_POST['q'];
echo $table;   //test display
```

Is unsafe code.